# Can I use Global variables in State Machine definition files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am working on a serverless project using AWS SAM which consists of lambda and State Machine resources (see the SAM template bellow). I am wondering if there is a way to define a "Global" variable in my state machine definition file the same way how we can use [Globals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html) for the SAM template.

The reason I would like to do that is to shorten my state machine definition. Right now there states that use exactly the same properties such as the `NetworkConfiguration` block for my Fargate task:

`definition.asl.json`

```
{
    "StartAt": "Generate Config",
    "States": {
        "Generate Config": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "${GenerateConfigFunctionArn}",
            "Next": "ETL"
        },
        "ETL": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "Next": "ETL",
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:region:11111111:cluster/clustername",
                "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:region:11111111:task-definition/taskdef",
                "NetworkConfiguration": {
                    "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                        "Subnets": [
                            "subnet-00d610225d369486e"
                        ],
                        "SecurityGroups": [
                            "sg-016650ff9ecd28a9a"
                        ],
                        "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
                    }
                },
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Phase-1-start",
                            "Environment": [
                                {
                                    "Name": "COMMAND",
                                    "Value": "etl"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "Well_Calc": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
            "End": true,
            "Parameters": {
                "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                "Cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:region:11111111:cluster/clustername",
                "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:region:11111111:task-definition/taskdef",
                "NetworkConfiguration": {
                    "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
                        "Subnets": [
                            "subnet-00d610225d369486e"
                        ],
                        "SecurityGroups": [
                            "sg-016650ff9ecd28a9a"
                        ],
                        "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
                    }
                },
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Phase-1-start",
                            "Environment": [
                                {
                                    "Name": "COMMAND",
                                    "Value": "calculation"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`SAM template`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MySAMPOC:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::StateMachine
    Properties:
      DefinitionUri: stateMachine/definition.asl.json
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        GenerateConfigFunctionArn: !GetAtt GenerateConfigFunction.Arn
  GenerateConfigFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/generate_config
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
```

Is the use of Globals (or similar) supported for state machine definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globals aren't support for `AWS::Serverless::StateMachine` at the moment. Some alternative options you can consider:

- Using `DefinitionSubstitutions` for some values: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-statemachine.html#sam-statemachine-definitionsubstitutions
- Step Function supports YAML in develop tooling now, so switching from JSON to YAML will save a bit on indentation and braces at least. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/aws-step-functions-adds-tooling-support-for-yaml/
- Use CDK to define your state machine. You can create custom constructs that encapsulate common properties. Obviously this isn't SAM, but you can integrate SAM resources with CDK apps or consider migrating parts of your application to CDK. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer and detailed suggestions! I think I would try the DefinitionSubstitutions and see how that works in my case.